# Javascript getter

Tags: javascript, object, get, getter

Given the following code are `foo`, `bar` and `baz` all effectively the same? What if any is the advantage of using the `get` keyword?

```
var getValue = function () {
  return 'value';
}

var foo = {
  value: getValue(),
};

var bar = {
  get value() {
    return getValue();
  },
};

var baz = {
  get value() {
    return 'value';
  },
};

console.log('foo.value', foo.value); // foo.value value
console.log('bar.value', bar.value); // bar.value value
console.log('baz.value', baz.value); // baz.value value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given the following code are foo, bar and baz all effectively the same?

No, not at all.

- `foo` will have a `value` property that will be the **result** of calling `getValue` when `foo` was created, and will not call `getValue` later.
- `bar` will have a `value` property that, when accessed like `bar.value`, calls `getValue` and returns its return value.
- `baz` will have a `value` property with the explicit value `'value'`.

The differences are:

- Whether `getValue` is called
- *When* `getValue` is called

This is more obvious with some logging and with a slightly updated version of `getValue`:

```js
var getValue = function () {
  var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  console.log("getValue called, returning " + value);
  return value;
}

console.log("Creating foo");
var foo = {
  value: getValue(),
};

console.log("Creating bar");
var bar = {
  get value() {
    return getValue();
  },
};

console.log("Creating baz");
var baz = {
  get value() {
    return 42;
  },
};

console.log("Calling foo");
console.log('foo.value', foo.value);
console.log("Calling bar");
console.log('bar.value', bar.value);
console.log("Calling baz");
console.log('baz.value', baz.value);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;;
}
```

The advantage (and disadvantage) to a getter is you can execute logic (such as calling `getValue`) in response to what looks like a simple property lookup (`bar.value`, rather than `bar.value()` or `bar.getValue()`).

Comment: Thank you @t-j-crowder for a clear and explanatory answer. I've learnt something today :)